# Can't install 'kubuntu-desktop' during 20.10 -> 21.04 Manual Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I had to manually wget hirsute and then sudo ./hirsute open the distribution upgrade however I get the below error on Setting new software channels.

```
Can't install 'kubuntu-desktop'

It was impossible to install a required package. Please report this as a bug using 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

I'm quite stuck now. I do not want to reinstall the entire OS only upgrade and then stay on LTS because wow this whole you cant upgrade thing... big surprise and pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

I got past the issue with two steps

```
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

2. and then I enabled downloading of all sources in the software updater.

It took a lot of messing around and half way completed steps to get it to populate with the hirsute packages. I think cancelling right after it started allowed me to complete a partial upgrade in which the sources populated?